# Practical use of Masterplan in first time DM

Tags: dnd-4e, tools

So, I have played D&D (and other RPG rules) off and on for a long time, and now have boys of an age that I could DM for them and have some good father/son/nerdy time. I have never DMed myself. I have played a couple of times where the DM used Masterplan, and I have to say they have run far more smoothly than when not using it. (Not to say that it's a requirement but it certainly seems to smooth out the mechanics of encounters and the use of a map in battle has made it a lot easier.)

In light of seeing this program in practice, I have decided that I will try DMing with this program. I have a DDI account, and now I'm wondering what my next steps in using Masterplan are. Is it possible to import player sheets as well? What about existing encounter libraries, do those exist somewhere?

**Update:**
I found a loader on codeplex: http://compendiumimport.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Anthony, you might want to break some of those specific thoughts out into their own questions (the add-on that can farm content, how to do encounters).

Comment: I actually cut out the loading portion and then made this into a "How do I get started with Masterplan" question, hopefully. The problem is that I am not entirely positive what the questions I need to ask. :-/

Comment: I'm certainly starting to feel that this is too localized.

Comment: "[No campaign plan survives first contact with the enemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Clausewitz)" - Carl Von Clausewitz, who knew he gamed?

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the [tutorials listed on the Masterplan site](http://www.habitualindolence.net/masterplan/tutorials.htm). The tutorials there show exactly what I needed to know. They are YouTube videos which show how he sets up the Keep on the Shadowfell Adventure, which was the adventure I was going to do anyway.

My problem was that I was reading the manual (which is very nicely done), and there is a lot more covered there than I actually need for a first time attempt at DM.

Comment: This isn't really an answer without a significant expansion. Some links to the tutorials with a relevant quote or two that helped you solve the issues described would be best

Comment: It probably doesn't matter much anymore since the program is no longer developed and for an older version of D&D, but either way here is an updated link to the tutorial videos for posterity: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1AE840374B0ECC6B